# 12.04 Alternate USB menu, can't boot or install

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

Used *Universal USB Installer 1.8.9.8* to make a USB stick with *Ubuntu 12.04 alternate i386*. Booted it.

On the menu, pressing enter on "Run Ubuntu from this USB" or "Install Ubuntu on a hard disk" does nothing. The automatic boot countdown appears at the bottom, counts down, and nothing again - resets automatic countdown, counts down, repeat indefinitely. No errors, nothing just happens.

"Test memory" starts, but cannot be stopped; ignores keyboard input and keeps running forever.

"Rescue a broken system" fails on the 4th step, loading stuff from the CD.

Comment: Hardware specifications, Please?

Comment: Pentium 4 @ 2.8 GHz, GeForce 6600 GT, 512 MB RAM, not sure about the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Used `Universal USB Installer` 1.8.9.8 to make a USB stick

I don't know what that program is but **you need to use the officially recommended [UNetBootin](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=unetnbootin&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Funetbootin.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=b-nBT-vWEeiJiAK4k4X8Bw&usg=AFQjCNFG2iJy14ueI6PKA0HBkn1cP-KoBg&cad=rja) utility** to create your USB stick.

The reason it's failing is because Grub is unable to locate the boot kernel image (initramfs), and that's probably the fault of Universal USB installer.